# basic steps to write own SDK for app dwonload tracking

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile, ads

before start telling any thing friends i have already searched for my required concept but did not get any useful thing. So We have server where developer can upload his app(iPhone or android) and can run its app download increase campaign. So important is that developer can also be able to watch like how much app downloads provided by any campaign, so how can i do that ?

what will be the development conceptual view for such tracking SDK ?

what if developer already integrated more than one different advertising servers campaigns SDK's ?

How we can decide due to which advertising server any developer app download happen due to us or some one else campaign ?

Please share any of your suggestions, advance thanks for any kind of help :)